# Why my Laravel on delete cascade is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Why my Laravel "on cascade delete" is not working? Could you help me?

```
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('account_id');
    $table->decimal('amount', 13, 2);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('revenues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('account_id');
    $table->decimal('amount', 13, 2);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->decimal('amount', 13, 2);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('revenue_id');
    $table->bigInteger('category_id');
    $table->bigInteger('subcategory_id');
    $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('payment_id')->references('id')->on('payments')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('revenue_id')->references('id')->on('revenues')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

My engine is InnoDB. 10.4.8-MariaDB, Laravel 6.

Comment: I think we need to see the rest of the transactions table. Are there more foreign keys on this table?

Comment: What sort of "not working" is occurring? Do you get errors? Does it just not delete? Do you see the cascade defined in MySQL?

Comment: I am deleting transaction record and would like to delete payment record using cascade delete.

Comment: You have misunderstood it my friend, `on delete cascade` means when any row in the main table (payments/revenues) is deleted the matching row in the dependent table (transactions) gets deleted automatically. It's not the other way around; for that you must delete manually

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

`$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

It's also good practice to declare foreign key constraints separately, after the tables have been created :

```
Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
    $table->foreign('payment_id')->references('id')->on('payments')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('revenue_id')->references('id')->on('revenues')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. However I added delete method in controller so I can delete related payment and revenue with transaction.